# get UIView height without tabbar

Tags: uiview, height, frame, uitabbar

Hi I have a simple uiview embed in a tabbar if I print the following:

```
NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.height);
```

I get "460.0" that looks like the height for the view without the status bar.

What if I want to get the height of the view without the tabbar?Anything cleaner than a subtraction?

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. My solution is to subview a UIView whose size precisely excludes the tab bar. Not that elegant, but I don't have to deal with subtraction and what not.